# How to add attribute to WCF message header with MessageHeader.CreateHeader() method?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I am adding a WCF custom header with the following code

```
 MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Key", "ns", "Value");
 OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
```

With this I also want to add

```
    xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
   wsa:IsReferenceParameter="1"
```

as an attribute to this Message header.

Is there any way to add above namespace and attribute to the message header?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found solution.
We have to Implement custome header, which is inhertied from MessageHeader class.

MessageHeader class does have method `OnWriteStartHeader()`. We can add xml namespaces in this method.

Also we have to override OnWriteHeaderContents() method and write xml or value we want as MessageHeader.

Once this is ready while adding message header in request.Header.Add() pass object of our custom header class.

Refer following links more details.

http://www.netframeworkdev.com/windows-communication-foundation/messageheader-serializer-how-to-use-attributes-52827.shtml

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c2a39df8-3943-4c41-acca-6da8e96f0dff

Answer (score 0):

Define an XmlSerializable class which serialises to the XML element format you want for your header. Then pass an instance of this class as the `value` parameter of `MessageHeader.CreateHeader`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the AddressHeader class it automatically adds the isReferenceParameter attribute. The following extension method to ChannelFactory would do what you wanted.

```
public static void AddHeader<T>(this ChannelFactory<T> factory, string headerName, string value, string nameSpace)
{
    var endpointAddressBuilder = new EndpointAddressBuilder(factory.Endpoint.Address);
    endpointAddressBuilder.Headers.Add(AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader(headerName, nameSpace, value));

    factory.Endpoint.Address = endpointAddressBuilder.ToEndpointAddress();
}
```